# Power Bi fetch metrics for calculation from multiple (dynamic) tables

Tags: powerbi

I have a dataset in Power Bi that imports 2 views from Snowflake:

- `HISTORIC_DATA` contains data older than 2022
- `Entry` contains data from 2022 onwards

They are two fact tables containing finance transactions with some logic to calculate the relevant `Account ID`, `Amount` and `Date` when the transaction was done.
In Power BI, I have joined those two tables with a third table, a dimension `Date` table on column `Date`.

i.e. `Entry.Date = Date.Date` and `HISTORIC_DATA.Date = Date.Date` in 1:Many relation.

The filter on page is on month and year hierarchy from `Date.Date` and we want to be able to select different months from different years.

I have some measures that work this way, e.g.

```
Revenue =  
IF(MAX('Date'[Year]) >= 2022, calculate(SUM(Entry[AMOUNT]), 
                        CONTAINSSTRING(Entry[Category], "1"))/1000,
CALCULATE(SUM(HISTORIC_DATA[actual]), 
                              HISTORIC_DATA[L1] = "Revenue", 
                              HISTORIC_DATA[REPORTITEM] = "Costs"
```

Everything works fine if I select multiple periods, I can display the spend per month, per different year.

The issue I have is when I want to sum up the last 12 months range across the two tables, e.g. Feb 2021 - Jan 2022. I used this formula:

```
LTM = 
CALCULATE (
    [PnL Value],
       DATESINPERIOD('Date'[Date],
               MAX('Date'[Date]),
        -1,
        YEAR
    )
)
```

Where `[PnL Value]` is a switch that contains many measures like Revenue, i.e.:

```
VAR Result = SWITCH(
    SELECTEDVALUE('PnL category'[name]),
        "Net revenue​", 'Measures Table'[Revenue],
    ...
)

RETURN Result
```

If I select 'January 2022' as filtered period, `DATESINPERIOD` goes back February 2021, but when this date range is passed to the measure inside `[PnL Value]`, e.g. Revenue, all the measures check `IF(MAX('Date'[Year]) >= 2022`, using the upper date bound of the filtered period, hence 2021 doesn't get calculated. But if I select e.g. 'January 2022' and 'January 2021'and show revenue for those two specific months, the formula `Revenue` works fine. It is on LTM that the `IF(MAX('Date'[Year]) >= 2022` excludes 2021, like it doesn't process each row but instead a grouped set.

How can I solve this?

**N.B** It would be time consuming to merge `HISTORIC_DATA`  and `Entry`  tables in one, as they are very different in format. I considered doing this exercise in Snowflake, where the data are stored, but I'd like to take it as last resource.

Can anyone help me in solving it so I can select many periods and be able to process date ranges splitting the calculation based on YEAR?

Thanks

Comment: Many of the measures defined in the switch are % if that helps and I used a matrix to display values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uhm here's a possible solution.

First, the measures need to be amended like this:

```
Revenue = 
var a = CALCULATE(
  SUM(Entry[AMOUNT]), 
  CONTAINSSTRING(Entry[Category], "1")
)/1000

var b = CALCULATE(
  SUM(HISTORIC_DATA[actual]), 
  HISTORIC_DATA[L1] = "Revenue", 
  HISTORIC_DATA[REPORTITEM] = "Costs"
)

RETURN COALESCE(a + b, 0)
```

For each measure, let's assume some of the ones you need are % then. So those ones have to be calculated and then divided for the total revenue.
I extracted it as common denominator here:

```
TRD = 
var total_revenue_denominator = SUMX(
  DATESINPERIOD(
    'Date'[Date], 
    MAX('Date'[Date]),
    -1,
    YEAR
  ),
  [Revenue]
)
```

for convenience. Then you apply it to your metrics, like in here:

```
var Result = 
SWITCH(
  SELECTEDVALUE('PnL category'[Name]),
  "Metric One %", 
  DIVIDE (
    SUMX(
      DATESINPERIOD('Date'[Date], MAX('Date'[Date]), -1, YEAR),
      [Metric One]
    ),
  total_revenue_denominator,
  0
  ),
  "Metric Two %", 
  DIVIDE (
    SUMX(
      DATESINPERIOD('Date'[Date], MAX('Date'[Date]), -1, YEAR),
      [Metric Two]
    ),
  total_revenue_denominator,
  0
  ),
  ... -- etc.
)

RETURN Result
```